# ¿Como hacer que un panel pueda abrir distintos control de usuario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo a hacer aplicaciones de escritorio en C#, el cual estuve leyendo que decian que era mala practica usar un windows form hijos cuando se queria poner sobre el windows form padre formulario, por lo cual recomendaban usar control de usuarios.

[image: Menú con panel central para abrir los formularios]

El problema es que logro abrir en el panel el control de usuario pero al querer seleccionar otra opción del menú no me abre y tengo claro que es porque nunca oculto el formulario anterior pero no se me ocurre como crear un metodo general para validarlo, he buscado tutoriales o alguna guia pero todos ocupan windows form para crear todos los formularios y el codigo que he intentado probar me tira error al leer el objeto.

Igualmente que si cambio la parte donde dice Form por userController me sigue tirando errores de ensamblaje

```cs
//Metodo para abrir formulario dentro del panel.
        private void abrirFormulario<MiForm>() where MiForm : Form, new()
        {
            Form formulario;
            formulario = panelCentral.Controls.OfType<MiForm>().FirstOrDefault();//Busca en la colección el formulario.

            //Si el formulario/instancia no existe
            if (formulario == null)
            {
                formulario = new MiForm();
                formulario.TopLevel = false;
                panelCentral.Controls.Add(formulario);
                formulario.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                //si el formulario/instancia existe
                formulario.BringToFront();
            }
        }
```

```cs
        private void btnViewListarEmpleados_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListadoCtrl uc1 = new ListadoCtrl();
            abrirFormulario<uc1>(); //Me tira error porque lo reconoce como variable y no tipo.
            //panelCentral.Controls.Add(uc1); // Este funciona
        }
```

Comment: Recordá que los generics hacen referencia a clases, no variables, deberías llamarlo como `abrirFormulario<ListadoCtrl>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendaria utilices `user controls` en lugar de `form` para mostrar en un `Panel`

```
private void abrirFormulario<ctrl>() where ctrl : UserControl, new()
{
    UserControl control = panelCentral.Controls.OfType<ctrl>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (control == null)
    {
        control = new ctrl();
        panelCentral.Controls.Add(control);
    }
    else
    {
        control.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

la idea es simplemente instanciar el control y lo asignas a la coleccion de controles

Pero crea un `UserControl` si quieres tener un diseñador similar al form solo que sin los bordes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]